# jQuery: Setting different sizes on images from ajax post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a js file which performs a ajax post and gets images from an URL.
The images are added to a 500x500 (px) div.
I want to set different size to every image I'm getting back from the ajax post...
I have 6 different image sizes that I would like to use.
So what I'm trying to achieve is to let picture number 1, 7, 13 have the same size
Picture 2, 8, 14 have the same size...etc

```
$.post(URL, function (data) { 
     var container = $("#container");
     container.html("");

      $.each(data, function () {
          var thumb = $("<div>");
          var image = $("<img>").attr("src", this.ImageUrl);
          var title = $("<span>").html(this.Title);

          thumb.append(title);
          // each picture will be faded in after 3.5 seconds
          thumb.append(image).fadeIn(3500);

          container.append(thumb);
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this might work:

```
//create an array with all the different sizes (widths and heights)
var sizes = [[100,100], [200,200],[300,300],[400,400],[500,500],[600,600]];

$.post(URL, function (data) { 
     var container = $("#container");
     container.html("");

      $.each(data, function (i) {
          var thumb = $("<div>");
          var image = $("<img>").attr("src", this.ImageUrl);
          var title = $("<span>").html(this.Title);

          //get the loop number and find the right image size in the array
          image.attr("width", sizes[i % sizes.length][0]);
          image.attr("height", sizes[i % sizes.length][1]);

          thumb.append(title);
          // each picture will be faded in after 3.5 seconds
          thumb.append(image).fadeIn(3500);

          container.append(thumb);
     });
});
```

I wrote a demonstration of it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qfpdgpfo/1/
note: I removed the whole ajax part in the demonstration as I don't have a url to post to, but the code should be the same:

Demonstration code:

```
//method 1
$(".method1 img").each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("width", sizes[i % sizes.length][0]);
    $(this).attr("height", sizes[i % sizes.length][1]);
});
//method2
$(".method2 img").each(function(i) {
    $(this).css({"width": sizes[i % sizes.length][0], "height":sizes[i % sizes.length][1]});
})
//method3
$(".method3 img").each(function(i) {
    $(this).addClass("size-" + i % sizes.length)
})
```

Comment: You could use CSS then add classes.

Comment: That's a good point. @Grendizer Consider adding classes like "size-1", "size-2", etc instead of setting width and height attributes. Also you could use the .css() method of jquery: image.css({"width": value, "height": value})

Comment: Thank you for an excellent answer! I knew modulus was the way to go!

Comment: Glad it helped. For the sake of completeness, I edited my answer and the link with all three version discussed in the comments of my answer